# Drupal 7 - dynamic, collapsible, navigation bar/block

Tags: drupal, navigation, drupal-7

Because a picture tells more than 1000 words.

On the left side, you will see what I need.
On the right side, you see what I already have.

**The question:**

Is there a possibility for showing all the chapters in a navigation block (or something simular) like a navigationtree ? with collapsible nodes and meanwhile if you click on some of those chapters, the main page changes?

perhaps with jquery?
But I can't find any good documentation whereby I can say, That's what I need.

I hope that someone can help

Kind regards.

Dieter

[image: 'a picture tells more than 1000 words']

EDIT : LINK to image --> [IMAGE FULL SCREEN](http://verbeemen.sinners.be//a/Nieuwe%20map/example.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu block module to solve the left item.  Create a base page or content type called History and then the content type that you have your "chapters" add them and set them as a child under the History node.  From here create a menu block and set the block on the left sidebar on the pages you want them on.

http://drupal.org/project/menu_block